# Can I use a 1 inch MIPT X 1 in. Slip PVC Union on a Hunter Anti-siphon valve 1" FPT threaded?

Tags: irrigation

Can I use a 1 inch MIPT  X 1 in. Slip PVC Union on a Hunter Anti-siphon valve 1" FPT threaded?

I'd like to connect the threaded part of male threaded part of the union to the female outlet of the Anti-siphon valve. Then I'd use PVC primer + glue on the slip end of the PVC union to attach to the 1" main irrigation supply line. I'd repeat this for the outlet side.

Am I missing something?

This is the [PVC Union](https://www.acehardware.com/departments/plumbing/pipe-fittings/plastic-fittings/4588802?x429=true&gclid=Cj0KCQiA0oagBhDHARIsAI-BbgdMsgOiVl84Iya8cN2nx-c_SznSNt6qNxKVo441_i2sodCs_7rDkpUaApTiEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds)

This is [the Hunter Anti-siphon Sprinkler Valve 1" female threaded](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00EDCGFDC)

Comment: what are you trying to do ?

Comment: I was trying to connect an anti siphon valve to a union so I can more easily replace them in the future without having to cut and glue pvc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what the fittings are made for, so I can't see any reason you couldn't do that.

Do use pipe dope or teflon tape on the pipe threads. I've come to prefer dope (I happen to use a teflon dope) over tape with some decades of using both.

Comment: Good answer, however Teflon tape can have tiny bits break off and primer has been known to do so as well.  Both can clog sprinkler nozzles.  Wife ran an irrigation manufacturing company for 30 yrs. They advised no Teflon tape and if the municipality did not require it no primer on irrigation system parts.  Thread sealing paste was ok on the anti- syphon valve.

Comment: Not having tape parts break off is a matter of competence in applying tape, but that's one reason I recommend dope (paste) instead for new users. More tolerant of less competence.